# Number of permutations of an integer

Tags: permutations

If $n$ is an integer, how many permutations are less than, equal to and greater than $n$?

For example if $n=24335$, $43325\gt n$, $23345\lt n$, etc...

Comment: The question is NOT clear to me enough

Comment: @S.Panja-1729; which bit is confusing?

Comment: How many permutations of $n$ are  $<n$ means ?

Comment: In this sense a permutation of $n$ appears to be a permutations of the digits of $n$...

Comment: Your question is somewhat ill-posed. There is no way to know without looking at where $n$ appears in a sorted list of all the permutations of its digits.

Comment: @MoseWintner; consider 123 132 213 231 312 321, can you say 231 is 4th, so 3 less than, 1 equal and 2 greater?

Comment: This depends on what $n$ is and I can see no way other than brute force of finding the number of permutations of its digits that are less than $n$.  For example if $n=55555$ there $5! = 120$ permutations of its digits but they are all $55555$ so none is less than n

Answer (score 1):

Interesting puzzle. You could figure it out recursively:

1. Start two variables ($b=0$ for bigger and $s=0$ for smaller).
2. Add all the permutations that have a bigger (smaller) initial digit to $b$ ($s$).
3. Remove the initial digit and go back to 2.

At some point you have 1 digit left which has only one permutation (equal).

This is basically just a restatement of your problem rather than a solution, but maybe it will help lead to something greater...

Answer (score 1):

Let $L(n), E(n), G(n)$ be the number of permutations less than, equal to, or greater than $n$, respectively.
Suppose the digits of $n$ are $d_1 d_2 \ldots d_m$ (in the usual order, most significant at the left).

I'll start with the case where all the digits are distinct.  Then $E(n) = 1$.
A permutation $d_1' d_2' \ldots d_m' < d_1 d_2 \ldots d_m$ iff for some 
$k = 1 \ldots m-1$, $d_i' = d_i$ for all $i < k$ while $d_k' < d_k$.
Let $R_k$ be the number of $i > k$ with $d_i < d_k$.  Then the number of
permutations with $d_i' = d_i$ for all $i < k$ and $d_k' < d_k$
is $R(k)(m-k)!$, so that $L(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} R_k (m-k)!$, and $G(n) = m! - 1 - L(n)$.  So for example with $n = 231$, $R_1 = 1$, $R_2 = 1$, and 
$L(231) = 1 \times 2! + 1 \times 1! = 3$.

EDIT: Mistake deleted.